# Setting Up Own CI service and Deploymentation

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration

I need suggestion for continuous integrations and deployment of some of my django project. Codeship and heroku r perfect. But I want to  deploy their feature on my hosting. I got Jenkins but still needed heroku replacement. Please suggest me to find currect apps.

Comment: I would suggest investigating options like: Dokku or Deis. These will provide a Heroku like environment

Comment: Thanks. Is docker needed for dokku?

Comment: Yes, docker is required for Dokku.